# Kafka Spark compatibility

Tags: python, apache-kafka

Thos code gives the error "no module named Kafka"

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
import time
import threading
import json
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

what are the compatible versions of K=kafka, oython and spark that prevent this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using any Spark libraries here.

You'll need to install kafka-python, it seems